# How can excluding types for array items be defined with OpenAPI/Swagger?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

[Swagger documentation explains how to define arrays that contain mixed types](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/), such as `["foo", 5, -2, "bar"]`. But, how can I define that an array must contain *either* one type of items (strings, `["foo", "bar"]`) or another (integers, `[5, -2]`)?

I've tried this, but Swagger UI can't render it, so I guess that it's wrong:

```
      oneOf:
        - items:
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/SchemaA'
        - items:
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/SchemaB'
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, remember that `oneOf` is only supported in OpenAPI 3.0 (`openapi: 3.0.0`) but not in OpenAPI 2.0 (`swagger: '2.0'`).

Your scenario can be defined using `oneOf` like so:

```yaml
oneOf:
  - type: array
    items:
      type: string
  - type: array
    items:
      type: integer
  - type: array
    items:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/SchemaA'
```

In vanilla JSON Schema, `type: array` can be moved out of `oneOf` and placed alongside `oneOf` but I'm not sure if OpenAPI allows this (the OpenAPI Specification is unclear on this).

```yaml
type: array
oneOf:
  - items:
      type: string
  - items:
      type: integer
  - items:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/SchemaA'
```

> I've tried this, but Swagger UI can't render it

Currently, Swagger UI does not automatically generate examples for `oneOf` and `anyOf` schemas (see [this issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3803)). The workaround is to add an `example` alongside `oneOf` manually:

```yaml
example: [1, 2, 3]  # <------
oneOf:
  - type: array
    items:
      type: string
  - type: array
    items:
      type: integer
  - type: array
    items:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/SchemaA'
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the array is a property of an object (`{my_property: one-of-array}`), should oneOf work there? With this, the problem is not only the example. The schema tab shows "oneOf" inside curly braces, so it looks like an object, not an array.

Comment: 1) Yes, `oneOf` can be used as a property schema. Just place `oneOf` where you would usually place `type: ...`. 2) _"schema tab shows "oneOf" inside curly braces, so it looks like an object, not an array"_ - This how Swagger UI currently displays `oneOf`/`anyOf` schemas. There's an existing feature request to improve `oneOf`/`anyOf` rendering - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4088

Comment: I think this issue has been resolved in the latest Swagger UI release.